Visual Studio Enterprise - Multiple Git Repos Under a Single Folder Structure

Currently in VSCode, it allows you to manage multiple git repos that are in the same folder. This functionality seems to be absent from Visual Studio:

I have tried multiple ways of getting this working, none of which have been successful. I initialized multiple repos under a single folder and then opened the folder in Visual Studio. At first this worked and all of the repos were listed as active and I could sync/commit etc to the git repos. However, I am not able to add any additional repos to it:

